# pool for Odoo objects from http.Controller class (python)

Tags: python, odoo

I'm new to Odoo (openERP) and python. I have an http.Controller in which I'm trying to retrieve a template which should contain some objects from openERP database, more specifically fleet_vehicle_log_fuel_obj. 
Usually the self.pool.get() method should do the trick, but in controller it doesn't work.

I'm trying to send some objects to the client and process them with javascript.

Here's my controller:

```
import json
from openerp import SUPERUSER_ID, pooler
from openerp.addons.web import http
from openerp.addons.web.http import request


class google_map(http.Controller):

@http.route(['/google_map'], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
def google_map(self, *arg, **post):
    cr, uid, context = request.cr, request.uid, request.context
    fleet_vehicle_log_fuel_obj = self.pool.get('fleet_vehicle_log_fuel');
    #fleet_vehicle_log_fuel_obj = pool.get('fleet_vehicle_log_fuel')
    ids = fleet_vehicle_log_fuel_obj.search(cr, uid, [])
    return request.website.render("fleet.google_map",  json.dumps(ids))
```

the error I get is 'google_map' object has no attribute 'pool'. How can i get all the objects of a certain type and send them to the client?

Comment: Instead of `self.pool.get` use `request.registry`.

Answer (score 3):

I know I have arrived too late, but may be this helps to someone.

The `http` library allows you to access the models from the controller, so you should write:

```
import openerp.http as http

fleet_vehicle_log_fuel_obj = http.request.env['fleet_vehicle_log_fuel']
```

And then you will be able to apply any ORM method with `fleet_vehicle_log_fuel_obj`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pool = request.registry
model_obj = pool['your.model']
```

**or**

```
model_obj = request.registry['your.model']
```

Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but try add to import:

> import openerp.pooler as pooler

Then use the code

> osv_pool = pooler.get_pool(dbname)
>
> osv_pool.get(model)

I got this from `openerp/osv/osv.py`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not able to test this anymore as I'm working on something else. Cheers!